# Android, GameOver Screen

Tags: java, android

I tried to create a gameover screen, which works, but well, when I launch my new screen, my back button does not work anymore.

Any idea what could cause this?

Here is my code:
http://code.google.com/p/android-climoilou/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fsrc%2Fclim%2Fandro

Comment: took a quick look... maybe try this.startActivity instead of AndroidClim.this.startActivity?

Comment: I don't think this copy of the code is all updated. The GameOverActivity isn't in your manifest which means it wouldn't work. Upload your current.

Comment: found my answer
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);

Answer (score 0):

Set the flags on intent to reorder your activities:

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
```